# How do I differentiate the type of EditText input when they have the equal length?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make an internet fetching (API call) from the text that user enters, but I want to have only one `EditText` field which is generic so that so many different types can be entered for convenience and the input should be handled.

I was thinking I can differentiate text types using their `String.length()` functions, but I have two inputs that requires different types (and thus requires different API calls) but they have the same string length.

I can try my luck and send to one API and if that returns null, I can use the other API call with ifs and elses. However, this is not efficient at all and for those who have weak internet connection, it is cumbersome. Any way to do it more efficiently? How do I differentiate?

Comment: Do you want differentiate your input type from the entered text. like number and text etc?

Comment: yes I want to do that. But it is not like "is it number or text" thing but rather it is a long string containing letters and numbers at the same time. Like a hash code. But one hash is for an attribute and another is for another :/

Comment: Did you try to solve this by using  `Pattern`

Comment: I do not have much idea what that is, can you please elaborate or at least direct ? Are you talking about the Java patterns ? Ah, no, hash codes do not have a template to set a pattern. Their number-letter sequence is interchanging.

Comment: yeah i am talking about  `Java  patterns`

Comment: As we can hit multiple call Asynchroniz. You can send the hash code in both API same time and implement the interface. So, one will have the result and another is null. In which API call you get the result, to send it to screen using the implemented interface object.

Comment: @Sunny that was what I was thought and suggested. I just did not want to make both calls at the same time for internet efficiency but I guess there is no other way. I'll use retrofit one after another and they'll be working on different threads anyway so I'll check nullity with ifs and do my stuff. Thank you. Still though if someone has **another solution**, I'd appreciate to hear it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you're using the EditText? Is it the same field on the same page for different inputs, or is it a custom extension of the EditText, which you want to be able to inflate on different screens. Your question is not clear.

Comment: it is the same field on the same page for different inputs. I thought I made it clear but no shame on clarifying it. you have another workaround to suggest? No extension or anything, just normal EditText. I'll use Intent in Button "Search" and send the data to another activity to make the API call.

Comment: Did you try maintaining a state as a member variable of the Activity/Fragment to determine which API needs to be called. Just update the state whenever the context of the EditText changes, and call the respective API accordingly.

Comment: @ShashankSaxena can you explain a little? It seems you caught something but you did not give any explicit answer or even a clue. How do I do it?

Comment: @bengongon97 Maintain a member variable(say mState). When taking input for first kind of input in EditText, keep the value of mState as "_state_1" (or something accordingly). For taking the second kind of input, update the member variable to "_state_2". And so on. When the user presses the button, check the value of mState, and call the respective API for that state.